# @OneToOne and @JoinColumn produces Expected value of type... exception

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

When I follow Doctrine's documentation for `@OneToOne` and `@JoinColumn` to create two ORM entity classes and then try to flush a persist operation I get the following error:

> Expected value of type "App\Entity\UserObject" for association field "App\Entity\LoginObject#$username", got "string" instead.

I have tried passing a string with the user's name and passing in an ORM entity object instance of the user object which produces an error that the login object is expecting a string. Either way I am unable to do this. The UserObject holds the user record. The LoginObject holds the login event timestamp with the username being a foreign key being in the user table.

```php
// UserObject.php:
class UserObject
...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
...
```

```php
// LoginObject.php:
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserObject")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="username", referencedColumnName="username")
     */
    private $username;

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
```

My expected results is that I expected the login object to be inserted into the database as a new entry, however that is not the case, any advise would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You should include the code that you wrote which is triggering this error. Nevertheless, the error message says it all—you've configured the `LoginObject::$username` property to be an associated field, so it expects an instance of `UserObject`. However, you are passing a string, and indeed the setter `setUsername()` accepts a string, not an object. Your relationship is misconfigured. I think you might be a little confused about associations so I recommend reviewing the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html) to clarify.

Comment: A question: what is the intent of the `LoginObject`—is it intended to log whenever a user logs in (implying that a `UserProfile` can be associated with more than one `LoginObject`)? If so, you probably want a `@ManyToOne` association on the `LoginObject`, not `@OneToOne`. And remember, the association has to be an object; e.g: `$login = (new LoginObject())->setUser($user);`

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things you didn't quite follow [the documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional). I suggest you read that again, but a bit slower ;) Compare it to this:

```php
class User {
    // make this the primary key (@ORM\ID)
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Login", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $login;

    public function getLogin(): ?Login
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    public function setLogin(Login $login): self
    {
        $this->login = $login;

        return $this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

```php
class Login {
    // make this the primary key (@ORM\ID)
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="login")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    // extra
    public function __invoke(): string
    {
        return $this->getUsername();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think in your User class you have to do mappedBy="username". But otherwise this seems like the correct solution to me!

Comment: Hmm, looked again due to your comment @LiamRoels, it was def not correct. Should be fixed now though ;)

Comment: I do not wish to set the $id as the primary key. The username should be the primary key. Also I do not wish to have the user object tied to the login object in a bi-directional method. I just want it so that in a traditional sense when I insert a record into the login table the username column must use a foreign key from the user object table. I do not want the id columns connected.

Comment: All good, set the `ORM\ID` on `$username` and some unique property in `Login` class, such as a duplicated `$username`. Using a uni-directional relation is also possible, just remove the reference on the user side. Mind that this duplication of data (having the `$username` stored more than once) is not good normalization of data, unless this `LoginObject` of yours is more a of a `LoginLog` or something. But such data and business logic is not clear in the question, as such I did not account for it and went with the most common use case.

Comment: Also mind that the [Working with Associations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#association-mapping) docs start of with: `Instead of working with foreign keys in your code, you will always work with references to objects instead and Doctrine will convert those references to foreign keys internally`. As such, a unique identifier must either referenced explicitly (so, a Primary Key `referencedColumnName`) or implicitly, by not at all declaring the `ORM\JoinColumn` Annotation (leave it out completely).

Comment: Both implicit & explicit methods of referencing another object require the usage of the `ORM\ID` Annotation on a unique property (id or username, whatever, so long as it's unique).

Comment: @jcohen7 above comments  ;-) (knew it was becoming more than 1 comment, so this as just a notice)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you need to set $username within LoginObject to an instance of UserObject, not a string.
Check out [this page in the Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html).